# aws parameterized pipeline creations with java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, jenkins-pipeline

I have below java code which is performing: 
1. activating pipeline. 
2. provide arguments to pipeline steps from java code.

```
ParameterValue parameterValue = new ParameterValue();
        parameterValue.setId("testId");
        parameterValue.setStringValue("testValue");
        List<ParameterValue> parameterValueList = new ArrayList<ParameterValue>();
        parameterValueList.add(parameterValue);
        ActivatePipelineRequest request = new ActivatePipelineRequest();
        request.setPipelineId(id);
        request.setParameterValues(parameterValueList);
            ActivatePipelineResult result = client.activatePipeline(request);
```

How can I read this parameter value in pipeline json:

```
pipeline{
  agent{
    docker{
      image'maven:3.3.3'
    }
  }
parameters {
        string(?)
    }
 stages{
    stage('build'){
      steps{
        sh'mvn --version'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Please help.

Comment: not sure so just throwing out an example of what we do incase it helps.      
import hudson.model.StringParameterValue .   
List<ParameterValue> parameters = [
        new StringParameterValue('PARAM', 'VALUE'),] .    
properties([
    parameters(parameters)
])

Comment: I am passing parameter using ActivatePipelineRequest but howcan i get those parameter in pipeline json

Comment: pipeline is not json, its groovy using the jenkins CPS interpreter. The pipeline steps (pipeline, agent, stage, steps, parameters, docker) are essentially groovy functions that accept closures as an argument. Im not sure how you would invoke from java, but essentially you need to pass your parameterValueList into the parameters{} closure